# fb request dialog appearing party out of window

Tags: dialog, request, facebook-canvas

I am asking for help, we have a request dialog in our app, but it appears partly out of the screen so its croped a bit on the right side.

We would like to center it so it wouldn`t be croped. Would anyone know how to fix that please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I'm not sure about the way how to position dialog itself. IMHO it can also depend on location of click event. Anyway, I've found ugly, but quite functional way to fix it with JavaScript:

```
setInterval("$('.fb_dialog').css('left', '0');", 1500);
```

Answer (score 0):

The dialog itself cannot be repositioned.

Are you using iframes in your code by any chance?

Try changing the width in your CSS file to something smaller and see if it makes a difference. The Request Dialog usually positions itself in the middle of a page by detecting the size of the page / frame.